# R- How to reshape Long to Wide with multiple variables/columns

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I started off with the following subset of my data

```
UserID labelnospaces             responses
1      Were you given any info?  yes
1      By using this service..?  yes
1      How satisfied are you?    Very satisfied
2      Were you given any info?  no
2      By using this service..?  no
2      How satisfied are you?    unsatisfied
```

By using the code below, I was able to get from long to wide perfectly

```
service_L_to_W<- reshape(data=service, idvar="UserID",
                         timevar = "labelnospaces",  
                         direction = "wide")
```

Using the code above, I got (this is what I wanted)

```
UserID   Were you given any info?   By using this service..?   How satisfied are you?
1        yes                        yes                        very satisfied
2        no                         no                         unsatisfied
```

**My question is how do I edit my code so that I can convert my data (with the extra variables/columns) from long to wide:**

```
UserID Full Name  DOB     EncounterID QuestionID Name  Type  labelnospaces           responses    
1      John Smith 1-1-90  13          505        Intro Check Were you given any info?  yes
1      John Smith 1-1-90  13          506        Care  Check By using this service..   yes
1      John Smith 1-1-90  13          507        Out   Check How satisfied are you?    vsat
2      Jane Doe   2-2-80  14          505        Intro Check Were you given any info?  no
2      Jane Doe   2-2-80  14          506        Care  Check By using this service..   no
2      Jane Doe   2-2-80  14          507        Out   Check How satisfied are you?    unsat
```

Comment: How does your expected output look ? Are you looking for `tidyr::pivot_wider(df, id_cols = c(UserID, Full.Name,  DOB,  EncounterID, Type), names_from = labelnospaces, values_from = responses)`

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some variables are can be better to together

```
df %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(UserID, Full.Name, DOB, EncounterID), names_from = c(QuestionID, QName, labelnospaces), values_from = responses)

  UserID Full.Name  DOB    EncounterID `505_Intro_Were you given any info?` `506_Care_By using this service..`
   <int> <chr>      <chr>        <int> <chr>                                <chr>                             
1      1 John Smith 1-1-90          13 yes                                  yes                               
2      2 Jane Doe   2-2-80          14 no                                   no                                
  `507_Out_How satisfied are you?`
  <chr>                           
1 vsat                            
2 unsat
```